# Dancer and template toolkit: <select> previous selected

Tags: perl, template-toolkit, dancer

I am using template toolkit, with perl Dancer. I have a form, and this form has a select.
I am trying after the form is submitted and the page returns to the same form, maintain the previous item selected in select. The Ldap_List contains 10 items.

This is the select code:

```
<form class="well form-inline" method="post" action="[% request.uri_base %]/foo/ldap">
<fieldset>  
<legend>Select the LDAP:</legend>
<select class="selectpicker" name="ldap_selected">
[% FOREACH ldap IN Ldap_List %]
   <option value=[% ldap %]>[% ldap %]</option>
[% END %]
</select>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go!</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

The variable with the last ldap selected is ldap_selected, and its defined and have the correct value, im checked it with:

```
[% IF ldap_selected %]
   [% ldap_selected %]
[% END %]
```

I tried this, but doesn't works:

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="ldap_selected">   
   [% FOREACH ldap IN Ldap_List %]
       [% IF ldap == ldap_selected %]
           <option value=[% ldap %] selected>[% ldap %]</option>
       [% ELSE %]
           <option value=[% ldap %]>[% ldap %]</option>
       [% END %]
   [% END %]
</select>
```

Because with that, in the select appears the ldap_selected, but its the only one option in the list.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a simple `HTML Form` Tag around the `Select` Tag and then read the `Form` Parameters inside your Perlscript with something like `params->{'ldap_selected'}`. I can suggest to read the [`Dancer` Documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer%3a%3aTutorial).

For this case you can start to take a look [here](http://p3rl.org/Dancer%3a%3aTutorial#Logging-in)

---

EDIT:

After your edit, it seems to be a `Template Toolkit` Problem. You said, that you have the Value of `ldap_selected` and it seems to be the value you need. `[% IF ldap == ldap_selected %]` is exactly the thing you need to do. Your Syntax is correct.

There are 2 Possible Problems/Solutions i can see there:

1. `ldap_selected` contains a newline or its not set.
2. `ldap` contains a newline.

Check with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> inside your browser the output of each variable. Maybe you can see a newline. Try the `IF ...` Part with an hardcoded `ldap_selected` (`[% IF ldap_selected == 'foo' %]`) and with

```
[% FOREACH ldap IN [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ] -%]
```

The `ldap` Part.

When nothing works, check if you maybe changed the Configuration of `TT` in your `MyWeb-App/config.yml`

Comment: I've edited my post, the select is inside a form. The problem is how to check inside the foreach if current element of the loop has the same value of ldap_selected

Comment: take a look at my EDIT :)

Comment: Thank you! Solved :) Newlines >.<